# Json parsing by RequestQueue Volley in fragments giving unexpected replies?

Tags: android, json

Hey I'm new to fragments in android. I have 3 fragments and this is second one. I want to have data set to its list view from the api by json. Im using Volley library.

But When i run this nothing is set on text view and logs show that requestqueue is running but its not showing up. I used the same thing in normal activity and its working there but not here.

Please help me out with this.

**TwoFragment .java**

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

RequestQueue requestQueue;
String url = "apiUrl";
ArrayList<HistoryEx> histories;
HistoryAdapterEx historyAdapter;
ListView lv;
TextView tv;


public TwoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, null);

    histories = new ArrayList<>();
    historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapterEx(getActivity(),histories);
    lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recentex);
    lv.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
    getRecent();



    return v;
}


void getRecent() {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());

    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("entries");

                        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jb = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                            String extype = jb.getString("type");
                            String exname = jb.getString("name");
                            HistoryEx history = new HistoryEx();
                            history.setExname(exname);
                            history.setExtype(extype);
                            histories.add(history);
                            tv.setText(exname);
                        }

                        //while ends to get object

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }//onresponse
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in loading history.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Volley", error.toString());

                }
            }

    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "jjhj");
            return headers;
        }

    };


    requestQueue.add(jor);
    /*
    end of Json parsing
     */
}




}
```

**HistoryAdapterEx.java**

```
 public class HistoryAdapterEx extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<HistoryEx> histories;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Activity activity;
public HistoryAdapterEx(Activity activity, ArrayList groups){
    super();
    this.histories =new ArrayList<>();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.histories =groups;
}

public int getCount() {
    return histories.size();
}


public Object getItem(int i) {
    return histories.get(i);
}


public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_ex1, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.exercise);
    TextView ac1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Achieved1);
    TextView ac2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Achieved2);
    TextView ac3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Achieved3);
    TextView ta1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.target1);
    TextView ta2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.target2);
    TextView ta3= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.target3);
    HistoryEx history = histories.get(i);
    System.out.println("ex.. "+history);
    name.setText(history.getExname());
    ac1.setText(history.getExname());
    ac2.setText(history.getExname());
    ac3.setText(history.getExname());
    ta1.setText(history.getExtype());
    ta2.setText(history.getExtype());
    ta3.setText(history.getExtype());
    //interests.setText(history.getDescription());
    //description.setText(history.getInterests());
    return view;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not set reference to TextView check below

Try below code,

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, null);

     histories = new ArrayList<>();
     historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapterEx(getActivity(),histories);


     tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.YOURTEXTVIEWID);
     lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.recentex);


     lv.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
     getRecent();
     return v;
 }
```

**Also Change Your Response Code as below**

```
           @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("entries");

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jb = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        String extype = jb.getString("type");
                        String exname = jb.getString("name");
                        HistoryEx history = new HistoryEx();
                        history.setExname(exname);
                        history.setExtype(extype);
                        histories.add(history);
                        tv.setText(exname);
                    }

                     historyAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

                    //while ends to get object

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }//onresponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very little mistake I Guess

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, null);

    histories = new ArrayList<>();
    historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapterEx(getActivity(),histories);
    lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recentex);
    lv.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
    getRecent();
    return v;
}
```

replace above code with below snippet

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, null);

    histories = new ArrayList<>();
    getRecent();
    historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapterEx(getActivity(),histories);
    lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recentex);
    lv.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didnt worked with that. I found the solution i didn't added historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after parsing :(

Comment: @AbhishekSeth that is because you haven't added anything to histories List before setting histories List to adapter and when you execute historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  the change in histories list reflect to adapter.

Comment: What if `getRecent` method has web-service call inside it? Will it wait before  returning view with data?

Answer (score 0):

It will be filled  after getRecent(); then call it before initialize adapter

```
   histories = new ArrayList<>();
   lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recentex);

    getRecent();
```

set it here is proper way   ..

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                       ....
                    }    
    historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapterEx(getActivity(),histories);  
            lv.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
```